# hard time with rewriting dynamic url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to convert the dynamic urls (with query string) of my website to friendly ones. That's the first time for me and I'm doing it for seo optimization.

I reached the point where if I type the friendly url, the browser sends me to the equivalent dinamic url (and I see the friendly url in the navigation bar), but if I navigate inside the website the navigation bar still shows me the url with the query. 
Is that right?

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.it
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.it/$1 
RewriteRule (.*).html$ /$1.php [R=302]
RewriteRule ^ita/([A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+).php$ $1.php?lang=it [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^eng/([A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+).php$ $1.php?lang=en [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ita/kiwishop/([A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+).php$ kiwishop.php?shop=$1&lang=it [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^eng/kiwishop/([A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+).php$ kiwishop.php?shop=$1&lang=en [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml ./sitemap.php [L]
```

Should I also do the opposite operation (I mean set a rewriterule that rewrite the dinamic url into the friendly one)? If so, how can I do that?

Another question: which url should I put in the sitemap.xml, the friendly one or the one with the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change all links on your site to the friendly URLs.

You should put in the sitemap whatever URL you want to show in search engines. It sounds like you want that to be the friendly URL.

Comment: @MargheritaBonaldi Great. If the answer solved your problem, you can also [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/3150271). That way, the system recognizes that the question is answered, and you get some reputation.